# Winner of a given game

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They have been given n (<50) numbers which lie between 1-1000. In one turn they can do either of the following
1.Decrement a number by 1.
2.Erase 2 numbers and write their sum.
A number when reached to 0 is automatically erased. A player loses if he cannot make any of the 2 moves. Given Alice plays first how can we tell who will win the game if both play optimally?

Can this question be done if one does not know game theory algorithms?

Comment: Are these all of the rules? You didn't mention how either player can win or lose.

Comment: sorry , i forgot to put the condition of losing. I have edited the question

Comment: What is "playing optimally" in this case?

Comment: "playing optimally" should mean that the player uses the best possible strategy available

Comment: I am guessing it is related to bits. Each number represents a bit vector in size of 10. You loose if all the bits vectors are zero, maybe except for one.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fleshed out a full solution, but I'm pretty sure you can get a solution without any game theory algorithms, just reasoning. Here are the useful bits that I hope will help you on your way:

Suppose the numbers at the start of the game are x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>. Note that only move 1 ever changes the total sum of all `n` numbers. Therefore, we immediately know in the beginning how many times Alice and Bob will make move 1 in total.

However, the number of times they make move 2 is not constant. To analyze how many times it will occur, note that move 2 and erasure of 0 terms are the only things that decrease how many numbers are currently written. Thus, the two of them will occur a total of `n` times between them, and at least one 0 must be erased (when the last decrement is done).

Since the number of times move 2 is done is not constant, while the number of times move 1 is done *is* constant, the driving force behind who will win is who can control the parity of the number of times either of them make move 2. On that note:

- Assuming you already know the parity of the sum of the numbers, who is perfectly okay with continuing to only make move 1, and who needs to have move 2 happen in order to win?
- How is the parity of `n` related with the above? (Note how the dynamic changes when someone makes move 2)

Any time one of the numbers is a 1, you can bet that a lot of thought will go into whether or not to decrement it (and erase the 0), or to choose this as one of the two numbers that will be replaced by a sum. That decision will be directly related with the above points.

Finally, if a move "must happen", what would the difference be between "making that move ASAP" and "stalling until the last possible moment to make that move"?